# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 for mac

Tags: objective-c, macos, cpu-architecture, podofo

I used podofo library for mac application development, while building demo app[image] i am getting following errors.

Comment: Seems like you make use of other libraries as well which you seemed to have missed in the linking step.

Comment: i have added the all required frameworks and libraries but still its showing same errors. @FlorianZwoch

Comment: Well if you add everything required its weird it still fails. Then again.. we don't know what you actually did..

Answer (score 0):

The error messages seem to indicate that you are working with static libraries (.a libraires). So, when building your demo app, you need to link with all the librairies needed, including the ones needed by freetype and fontconfig. These are bz2, z, crypto (from the openssl distribution) and others...

If Podofo is built with cmake, you can look at the CMakeCache.txt file. It contains the path where each library Podofo depends on was found on your system.

The bz2 library is not listed in the CMakeCache.txt. It is there by default, so you may just add

-lbz2

to the "Other Linker Flags" in your Xcode project build settings.